# bundler version exists, but RubyGems claims otherwise

Tags: rubygems, bundler

When I run `rails generate migration`, I get:

`/Users/bob/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:277:in 'find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.2.21) required by your /Users/bob/path/to/my/project/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)`

...followed by:

```
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.2.21`
```

However, `bundler` is clearly there:

```
$ gem list bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (2.2.21)

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.4p191 (2021-07-07 revision a21a3b7d23) [x86_64-darwin19]

$ find ~/.rbenv -name "*bundler*" | grep 2.7.4 | grep gemspec

/Users/bob/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/specifications/bundler-2.2.21.gemspec
/Users/bob/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.21/bundler.gemspec
```

I traced it down to [line 267 in rubygems.rb](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems.rb#L267):

```
specs = dep.matching_specs(true)
```

(It returns an empty array, I believe to suggest that it cannot find a matching spec.)

Note: I followed the above instructions/suggestions (of running `bundle update --bundler` and `gem install bundler:2.2.21`) to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me:

```
rbenv uninstall 2.7.4

rbenv install 2.7.4

bundle

git restore Gemfile.lock   # there were some insignificant rearrangments
```